# Angular JS Inject Error while execute TDD with Karma & Jasmin

Tags: angularjs, tdd

we developing an application using Angular Js and Web API.

I'm working on Front end TDD for Angular Js.

I'm Stuck with the following error,
***`Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?`***

This is my file structure,
 -> app.js in root folder,

```
var app = angular.module('RevFlexApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ui.bootstrap', 'flash', 'mb-scrollbar', 'smart-table', 'ngFileUpload', 'simplePagination', 'mdo-angular-cryptography', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

1. -> Modulename->*.Js Filename
2. -> Modulename->*Spec.Js Filename
3. -> UnitTest->Modulename->*Spec.Js Filename*  (Optional)

How can i solve the inject error.

Comment: May i know your app name..? because sometime your app name is different then also it will fire the same error.

Comment: My App Name: RevFlexApp;

Comment: Sample TDD:





describe('defectsCtrl TDD -', function () {

    beforeEach(module('RevFlexApp')); 

   // Failed Area
    it('should have a defects controller',
           inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
               var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
               $controller('SignupCtrl', {
                   $scope: $scope
               })
               expect($scope.GetMyId(1)).toEqual(parseInt(1));
           })
        );

    it('should come 25', function () {
        var result = 25;
        expect(result).toBe(25);
    }); 
});